# Exception during split the string

Tags: java, android

I'm have the following string `str = "one|two|three|four|five"`
I try to split it using `str1[]=str.split("\\|");`, but it shows exception while debugging.
The error is `Exception processing async thread queue`. What's this and how to do it?

Comment: Could you paste your code here?

Comment: `What's this and how to do it?` What do you mean?

Comment: String str = "one|two|three|four|five";
String[] StrCheck = str.split("\\|"); . this is my actual code ,, i put a breakpoint on straight to str and debug the code.if i put my cursor(mouse cursor) on StrCheck one pop up comes states that" Exception processing async thread queue
Exception processing async thread queue
Timeout occurred while waiting for packet 5980." i dont know y this will occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
 String tempString="one|two|three|four|five";
 String str1[]=tempString.split("\\|");
       for(int i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
       {
           Log.i("Str1["+i+"]",str1[i]);
       }
```

Result is,

```
Str1[0]: one
Str1[1]: two
Str1[2]: three
Str1[3]: four
Str1[4]: five
```

Comment: str="one|two|three|four|five";

Comment: couldn't get you. What r u trying to mean??

Comment: String str = "one|two|three|four|five"; String[] StrCheck = str.split("\\|"); . this is my actual code ,, i put a breakpoint on straight to str and debug the code.if i put my cursor(mouse cursor) on StrCheck one pop up comes states that" Exception processing async thread queue Exception processing async thread queue Timeout occurred while waiting for packet 5980." i dont know y this will occurs

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one...

```
in = "Your String";  
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in, "|");  
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {   
  String str = st.nextToken();  
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: dont use `StringTokenizer`, StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: +1 @Nandkumar I didn't know this and I've used StringTokenizer a few times lately. JVM should give a deprecated warning or something.